# Remove branches for remote that no longer exists

Tags: git

When I run the command `git branch -a` I see a list of branches associated with a remote that no longer exists.
ex:

```
remotes/does-not-exist/branch1
remotes/does-not-exist/branch2
remotes/origin/dev
remotes/origin/feature3
```

I want to remove the branches associated with `does-not-exist` from the list above. However if I run the command `git remote prune does-not-exist` I get the following error

```
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

How can I remove the branches associated with `does-not-exist`? Should I just delete the folder under `.git/refs/remotes/`?

Comment: For the time being, I "resolved" this issue by blowing away the local repo folder and cloning from the remote again.

Answer (score 4):

I merged a branch to the master using the GitLab web page.

On my local shell, the branch was still present

```
git branch -a
* 9-deploy
master   
remotes/origin/9-deploy   
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master   
remotes/origin/master
```

Deleted the local branch with

```
git branch -d 9-deploy
```

Deleted the reference to the remote branch with

```
git fetch -p
```

Used the following [reference](https://suhasjavablog.wordpress.com/2018/04/09/git-remove-local-branches-which-are-no-longer-on-remote/) to find commands

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was finally able to remove them using `git branch -Dr does-not-exist/branch1`.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the remote, not branches. By this the branches will be deleted too. `git remote remove does-not-exist`.

Comment: Thanks, @kan. I tried this, and perhaps I am just in a bad state, but this did not work for me.

Comment: I ran the command you provided, and then ran `git branch -a` again and I still saw the branches associated with the remote that no longer exists.

Comment: @AaronHoffman however, forced method to delete a reference is `git update-ref -d remotes/does-not-exist/branch1`.

Answer (score 0):

To delete remote branches, I run `git push origin --delete <branch>`. So in your case, you may run the following:

```
git push does-not-exist --delete branch1
git push does-not-exist --delete branch2
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @dlstadther, however this is not working for me. The remote itself no longer exists, so attempting to delete the remote branch also does not exist. I get the same error as `git remote prune` above.

Comment: @AaronHoffman Have you found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072171/how-do-you-remove-an-invalid-remote-branch-reference-from-git)?