# Can't delete branch even though it shows up in git branch

Tags: git

`git branch -r --merged | grep 123`

OUTPUT

origin/feature/123-some-feature

`git branch -r --merged | grep 123 | xargs git branch -d`

OUTPUT
error: branch 'origin/feature/123-some-feature' not found.

Why can't I delete this remote branch?

**EDIT:**
Sorry, should have been more clear on my initial post (I was in a meeting when I wrote this). I don't have any of these branches locally and I'm trying to do a cleanup of the remote repository to delete all merged branches (I'm testing it by filtering to just '123' for now).

I want to get a filtered (via grep) list of the remote branches that have been merged so I can review them locally to be sure I'm not going to delete any branches I want to keep.

Then I want to execute it again with `| xargs git branch -d` to actually remove those branches from the remote repository.

I think this would be what I want based on the posted answer and one of the comments?

`git branch -r --merged | grep 123 | xargs git push origin --delete`

Comment: To delete a remote branch you need to `git push --delete` (or `git push origin :branch`, notice the colon), not just `git branch -d`

Comment: Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, this may be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1072171/1157054

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't delete it because it's a *remote* branch.  It exists in the remote repository, not in your local repository.  If you want to delete it *on the remote*, you can:

```
git push --delete origin feature/123-some-feature
```

But understand that this will affect the availability of the branch *on the remote repository*.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. I actually want to delete these branches on the remote repository.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use `git branch -r` to delete remote branch. 
Use `git push origin :your/branch/name` (be sure you entered colon `:` before branchname)

Comment: why would you post a more cryptic version of the accepted answer (using a colon `:` is the same as saying `--delete`)?