# How do I delete old remote refs that are no longer valid

Tags: git

I have a few old pull requests that are no longer valid, but their refs are still hanging around.

`git ls-remote`
[image]

how do I go about removing these old refs on the remote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove an invalid remote branch reference from Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072171/how-do-you-remove-an-invalid-remote-branch-reference-from-git)

Answer (score 4):

You could, on the server itself, use `git update-ref` to delete these references.  That method is more or less guaranteed to work—but requires that you be able to log in on the server itself.

The in-Git alternative, which may or may not be allowed by the server, is to send the server a push request of the form "delete ", using, e.g.:

```
git push --delete origin refs/pull-requests/70/from refs/pull-requests/70/merge
```

or equivalently:

```
git push origin :refs/pull-requests/70/from :refs/pull-requests/70/merge
```

The server might *reject* this request, saying that references in the `refs/pull-requests` namespace are reserved.  If that's true, you're stuck with either:

- log in on the server and use a Git command there, or
- bypass Git entirely, perhaps by using a web interface.

It seems likely that the web interface (or similar) is the *raison d'être* for the use of that particular server in the first place: through their web interface, they provide features like "fork repository" and "make pull request".

Comment: That looks like it would work if I had the correct access from the server itself to do this. But I am currently being blocked the product because it is managed internally by the product itself. Here is the message returned from the server for reference: `remote: You are attempting to update refs that are reserved for Bitbucket's pull request functionality. Bitbucket manages these refs automatically, and they may not be updated by users.`

Comment: "The server might *reject* this request ... if that's true, (bullet points)". I note you never mentioned bitbucket specifically in the question (nor in tags).